# Nx, Angular, Jest and Sonar

Tags: angular, jestjs, sonarqube, nomachine-nx

I'm looking for a recipe to use with an Nx (13.4.1) Angular (13.1) Workspace using Jest to run unit tests.  I want to generate and publish unit test run results and coverage reports to SonarQube server individually for each library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Create Nx Angular Workspace with Multiple Angular Libraries**
https://nx.dev/angular

(for this recipe, library folder structure must be of the form `./libs/my-scope/my-library`)

**(Optional) Create Local SonarQube Server via Docker**

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:latest
```

(change credentials from admin / admin to something else)
https://www.sonarqube.org/features/deployment/

**Setup SonarQube Scanner**

Quick Start Article - Setup SonarQube for Angular
https://codeburst.io/setup-sonarqube-for-angular-application-locally-in-three-easy-steps-8f31e339ac19

```
npm install -g sonar-scanner
```

**Modify jest.config.js in each library**

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'my-scope-my-library',
  preset: '../../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
    },
  },
  coverageReporters: ["clover", "json", "lcov", "text", "text-summary"],
  collectCoverage: true,
  testResultsProcessor: "jest-sonar-reporter",
  coverageDirectory: '../../../coverage/libs/my-scope/my-library',
  transform: {
    '^.+.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*.mjs$)'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  ],
};
```

(these three lines were added)

```
  coverageReporters: ["clover", "json", "lcov", "text", "text-summary"],
  collectCoverage: true,
  testResultsProcessor: "jest-sonar-reporter",
```

**Install jest-sonar-reporter npm package**

```
npm install --save-dev jest-sonar-scanner
```

**Create `sonar-project.properties` in workspace root**

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=
sonar.inclusions=**/*.ts, **/*.scss, **/*.html
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
```

**Create bash script to loop through the scopes and libraries**

```
scopes=$(ls libs)
for scope in $(echo $scopes); do
  libs=$(ls libs/$scope)
  for lib in $(echo $libs); do
    echo "$scope -- $lib"
    nx test "$scope-$lib" --code-coverage || true
    mv test-report.xml coverage/libs/$scope/$lib

    # run sonar scanner to anaylize and publish results
    sonar-scanner \
      -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN \
      -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL \
      -Dsonar.projectKey="optional-prefix-$scope-$lib" \
      -Dsonar.sources=libs/$scope/$lib/src \
      -Dsonar.tests=libs/$scope/$lib/src \
      -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/libs/$scope/$lib/lcov.info \
      -Dsonar.testExecutionReportPaths=coverage/libs/$scope/$lib/test-report.xml

  done
done
```

Comment: How do I use the bash file and it for?

Comment: typo in the "install jest-sonar-reporter" step. Should be:

`npm install --save-dev jest-sonar-reporter` instead of scanner